# Background music in python

Tags: python, audio

I'm making a game where you're a space shuttle evading oncoming meteors, this is my first Python program and I really struggle with the music part: the idea is to only use `wxPython` (`pyGame` is forbidden).

Currently I somehow managed to get the music to play when you click on a button, but then I can't control the space ship anymore.

I don't fully understand what's going on, I've been searching for days with no answers.

```
class Board(wx.Panel):
BoardWidth = 5
BoardHeight = 12
Speed = 50
ID_TIMER = 1

def __init__(self,parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self,parent)

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self, Board.ID_TIMER)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, id=Board.ID_TIMER)
    self.ClearBoard()

    self.music = wx.Panel(self)
    button = wx.Button(self, label="Play")
    self.music=wx.media.MediaCtrl(self.music, -1, "game.mp3")
    button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.play)

def play(self,event):
    self.music.Play()
```

As far as I'm concerned this how I imagine it should work, but it doesn't:

```
    #...
    self.music=wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, -1, "game.mp3")
    self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)

def play(self,event):
    self.music.Play()
```

Comment: Who cares? But no, semester project and this is pure bonus from me, pyGame is still forbidden as it's too easy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a thread to play the music. Right now your frame freezes while it waits for the music to finish, which of course never happens, as it is background music.
There is a strange bug where the event is never generated. To solve this, add `szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10` (see code below)

try:

```
import threading
#...

self.music=wx.media.MediaCtrl(self.music, -1, "game.mp3",
                              szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)    

#...
def play(self, event):
    threading.Thread(target=self.music.Play).start()
```

Alternatively, you could use a timer to wait for the file to be loaded:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    #...
    self.play()

def play(self):
    threading.Timer(0.5, self.music.Play).start()
```

Comment: Don't use the `thread` module. Use the higher-level [`thrading`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading) module.

Comment: +1 you are right, I edited the answer. I must admit that I didn't know too much about threading in python, I originally got it from http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks and didn't look much further then. Thanks to you, I have learned something myself too. :)

Comment: Still doesn't work, I get to move my space ship, but still no music.

Comment: @Nurgak, There is some bug in the wx.media.MediaCtrl widget. I edited my post with two workarounds.

Comment: Thank you, I finally was able to make the game work thanks to your code and the threading. My other mistake was to put the self.play() in Board and not in Frame. I'll show my grade after I pass the test.

Comment: @Nurgak, I'm glad you were able to solve it (although I don't see what difference it makes if the self.play() is in the Frame or Board). As it seems that this answer solved your problem, please **accept** it, by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks :) I hope you get a good grade!